# Save a text file from PHP and AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a file in the C: drive

```
'C:/myFile.txt'
```

I know the path and I simply want the user to save the file. However I try to use javascript

```
window.location.assign('C:/myFile.txt');
```

I get the path name not being understood.

I also try

```
window.open('C:/myFile.txt');
```

So I was thinking to send an AJAX request to PHP, supply the path, and use fopen. I do that and pretty much nothing happens.  I need it to prompt as a download/save as.

Comment: A web browser cannot interact with your files other than a file upload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this server is remote to the user, they will not be able to download a file with a path from your C: drive in their browser.

You will need to place the file somewhere in your web root and then use its URL for downloading: `window.location.assign('http://www.example.com/myFile.txt');`